# Wordpress: Insert attachment with current full path to image NOT located in wordpress Uploads Directory

Tags: php, wordpress

I am attempting to write a plugin that, upon activation, programmatically does everything that is needed to upload an image to the `uploads` directory.  In other words: it does everything that would happen if you manually did the drag-and-drop of the image on the `Add New` Media Library Screen:

[image: add media]

**Details:**

- I am not submitting a POST request.  I am simply trying to find out what functions I need to call in order to do the following (which wordpress does in the drag-and-drop Media Library screen:

  - Find and grab the image specified by the FULL path (example: image is located on the desktop.  It is NOT in the `uploads` directory).
  - Upload that image, as well as various versions of that image, in the `uploads` directory
  - create a `post` of `post_type` equal to `attachment`
  - create relevant `postmeta` records

Example:

It seems like [wp_insert_attachment](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_attachment/) simply cannot do this because the image MUST already exist in the uploads directory.

```
# Below is a comment from the wp_insert_attachment example:
// $filename should be the path to a file in the upload directory
```

[This post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/176577/file-path-for-attachments-outside-of-wp-content-uploads) just says this isn't possible with `wp_insert_attachment` but does not provide a solution.

**Question(s)**:

- How can I programmatically upload an attachment whose path does not exist in the wp-content/uploads directory? Instead, for example: the full path to the image is located on the desktop.
- Is this simply impossible to do without doing it in the context of uploading the image via a form and POST request?  Ideally I want to call some function that says "Here is the full path to the image which is located on the desktop.  Now: do all the work necessary to upload the image within the context of my wordpress project."

Thanks!

Comment: You need to create a form with input field of `file` type and submit the form which can upload the file to WordPress wp-content.

Comment: @SamiAhmedSiddiqui the images already exist on the server.  Ultimately I want to import them in so that it creates the `attachment` post_type, the various sizes, and the meta data.

Comment: @SamiAhmedSiddiqui Updated my question. Let me know if that helps clarify what I am trying to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw you were referencing your server's desktop. Make sure that the files you are trying to load are accessible by the WordPress App User!

If you have to do this programmatically, it looks like media_handle_sideload might do the trick. Same functionality as media_handle_upload, but I don't think it requires the POST request to activate it like media_handle_upload does.

So
Step 1: Move files to location accessible by the WordPress application (like wp-content/uploads)

Step 2: grab url for the file you need to "upload" (something like host/wp-content/uploads/image.jpg)

Step 3: Figure out the post Id you need to reference for the image, and use media_handle_sideload to validate and store the file (code snippet below from the [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_sideload))

```
<?php 
// Need to require these files
if ( !function_exists('media_handle_upload') ) {
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
}

$url = "http://s.wordpress.org/style/images/wp3-logo.png";
$tmp = download_url( $url );
if( is_wp_error( $tmp ) ){
    // download failed, handle error
}
$post_id = 0;
$desc = "The WordPress Logo";
$file_array = array();

// Set variables for storage
// fix file filename for query strings
preg_match('/[^\?]+\.(jpg|jpe|jpeg|gif|png)/i', $url, $matches);
$file_array['name'] = basename($matches[0]);
$file_array['tmp_name'] = $tmp;

// If error storing temporarily, unlink
if ( is_wp_error( $tmp ) ) {
    @unlink($file_array['tmp_name']);
    $file_array['tmp_name'] = '';
}

// do the validation and storage stuff
$id = media_handle_sideload( $file_array, $post_id, $desc );

// If error storing permanently, unlink
if ( is_wp_error($id) ) {
    @unlink($file_array['tmp_name']);
    return $id;
}

$src = wp_get_attachment_url( $id );
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the file already on the server, but it doesn't have a path setup in wordpress yet (i.e. you can't browse to it from a web browser), there's a plugin called ["Add from Server"](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-from-server/) where it opens a miniature file browser window that's connected to your server, and then it creates the database records in your WordPress instance to the files residing on the server, so that you can pull them up in the media browser on wp-admin.

Warning though, this plugin is a security risk since the plugin essentially gains file-access to your webserver's directory. If you have to, say, bulk upload a bunch of files to WordPress and they're already on the server, I would install the plugin, create the database records for the files, and then immediately deactivate and uninstall the plugin!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for media_handle_upload.  You can then use wp_update_attachment_metadata.

Here is a basic version:

```
<?php

// Use 0 as your post ID if you don't want to attach it to any post
$image = media_handle_upload($file, $post_id);

wp_update_attachment_metadata( $image, $data ); 

?>
```

You can see a more advanced version [using a frontend form here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_handle_upload/#user-contributed-notes).

You could alternatively use media_handle_sideload if uploading an image from a URL.

Comment: hmm: `media_handle_upload` did not add the image to my uploads directory.  It appeared to do nothing.  I ran `media_handle_upload('C:\Users\some_user\Desktop\my_pic.png', 0)` within my plugin, activated the plugin, and it doesn't appear to do anything.  It appears that `media_handle_upload` is for a `POST` request, but I am not submitting a form at all.  To be clear: I am not submitting a form on the front-end.  I am trying to grab an image that is located elsewhere on my computer, and upload it programmatically just like how wordpress does it when you upload media.

Comment: I updated my question.  Hopefully that helps clarify what I am trying to figure out.